# How do you provide a GasPrice and GasLimit to overcome the "low tx nonce or out of funds" log message

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, gas-limit, gas-price, truffle

I am getting the following logged by my private chain geth node when running a test in truffle:

```
removed tx (
    TX(ff8ec4f713e64fb25df07d153607e29629c9276b57e0b7e331f17b5a3c31fdd1)
    Contract: false
    From:     d90b704c738b49ff50741bd887334e49d8f277f1
    To:       [contract creation]
    Nonce:    520
    GasPrice: 18000000010
    GasLimit  3200000
    Value:    0
    Data:     0x606060405..........
    V:        0x1b
    R:        0x5b......
    S:        0xe09017.......
    Hex:      f901c3.......
) from pool: low tx nonce or out of funds
```

The test code is as follows:

```
contract('MyContract', function (accounts) {

    it("should be able to set a value", function (done) {

        var myContract = MyContract.deployed();

        myContract.setValue("aStringValue", 2, {from: accounts[0],gas: 3200000, gasPrice: 18000000010}).then(
            function (tx_id) {
                return zone.isValueSet.call("aStringValue");
            }).then(
            function (_bool) {
                assert.isTrue(_bool, "value not set");
                done();
            }).catch(done);
    });

});
```

I have confirmed that the GasPrice and the GasLimit reflect those provided in the test and that providing them in an object, as the last arg to the contract function, is correct.

There are sufficient funds in accounts[0] so I do not know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

The `low tx nonce or out of funds` error message means that you either don't have enough funds to cover all the gas requirements that you specified (i.e. gas limit * gas price); or that the nonce you are sending the transaction with is lower than the one already used by your sending account.

Perhaps log all the transactions that you issue and check if truffle for some reason creates multiple transactions with the same nonce. That might explain the issues you are seeing.

Comment: Since asking this question I have moved on and got my complete contract working on Geth (Geth/v1.4.0-rc-8241fa52) but this complaint continues to be reported on all my contract transactions. There was an issue reported once https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/1368 . Maybe it came back.