# Should correct transaction nonce be one less than account transaction count?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, gas, out-of-gas, nonce

I am trying to solve the 'Why am i getting “removed tx from pool: low tx nonce or out of funds”?' problem on my private test net.

I seem to have enough funds however the rejected transaction nonce is always one less than the transaction count of the sending address:

```
I0427 16:02:49.456986   84576 tx_pool.go:492] removed tx (
    TX(cf149f29fdb9ee3fe4f6b3907d396e8fd5abc832e21ee5453c9702003b5fd62a)
    Contract: false
    From:     db575481f1d1b626b9a0ee2f2c6946b3f6526cd4
    To:       [contract creation]
    Nonce:    6
    GasPrice: 20000000000
    GasLimit  1062420143
    Value:    0
    Data:     0x
    V:        0x1c
    R:        0x7832879e31c8c679779c34f0004a38e3e64848ce9a92757cebb11d792ccb1435
    S:        0x28d0b672e4b904d972d221df2c53250a9884b13142a63c9be193537557b241ea
    Hex:      f852068504a817c800843f533eaf8080801ca07832879e31c8c679779c34f0004a38e3e64848ce9a92757cebb11d792ccb1435a028d0b672e4b904d972d221df2c53250a9884b13142a63c9be193537557b241ea
) from pool: low tx nonce or out of funds



> eth.getTransactionCount("db575481f1d1b626b9a0ee2f2c6946b3f6526cd4") 
7
> eth.getBalance("db575481f1d1b626b9a0ee2f2c6946b3f6526cd4");
7.4699999999999996e+21
```

Is the tx nonce and transaction count consistent here?

If the nonce is zero indexed then I guess that they are. If that is the case I have no idea why I am getting this error message. This is driving me crazy. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is db575481f1d1b626b9a0ee2f2c6946b3f6526cd4 your address and are you on the main net? Because I'm not seeing any transactions for that account so the nonce should be 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the nonce is zero indexed. Given that it's zero indexed and you have 7 executed transactions, means that the last used nonce was 6. So the next valid one needed for the pool to accept it is 7 (i.e. the same as `eth.getTransactionCount`).

Comment: Thank you very much @Péter. In that case both my funds and nonce seem to be ok. Do you have any idea why else my transactions might be getting removed?

Comment: In the sample above, the nonce of the removed transaction is 6, whereas it should be 7, per my explanation.

Comment: Are you implying that the transaction count should not increase if a transaction is removed i.e unsuccessful? In reference to the question, the transaction count before I submitted the failing transaction above was indeed 6 (the same as the nonce). My transaction count is increasing even when transactions are 'removed'.

Comment: The transaction count is the number of successfully executed transaction. (unless you are requesting the pending transaction count, which you are not above). So if it says 7, then that many transactions from the account have already been included in the blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

This [comment](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3363/how-do-you-provide-a-gasprice-and-gaslimit-to-overcome-the-low-tx-nonce-or-out#comment3420_3408) on a similar question provided the answer for the second part of this question - why transactions are being removed when nonce and funds are valid?

It appears that, despite this error message, my transaction DOES get mined successfully. This can be checked by [getting the transaction receipt](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactionreceipt) for the supposedly 'removed' transaction.

FYI: I am using geth v1.3.6